# .four plot FF/t LTspice

Tags: ltspice, fft, plot

I am trying to plot an FFT in LTspice using a `.four` command and the spice error log directly without using the FFT on LTspice (right click + view + FFT once the simulation is finished).

How is it possible to plot the data of the `.four` command at the end of the simulation from the spice error log?

Here is an example of the spice error log:

[image]

I cannot right click on the spice error log and plot FFT measured by the `.four` command.

Comment: It can't plot it before the sim is ran so it has to be afterwards.

Comment: If all else fails, extract that part of the file and import it into a spreadsheet. (But the data shown is only the harmonics, not the full FFT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't plot the result of the `.FOUR`, that's meant to be a report in the error log, only. But you can plot the FFT of a waveform by making the waveform viewer window active > <kbd>RClick</kbd> > *View* > *FFT*. For the best results, be sure to include an integer number of periods for the waveform.